# Duplicate pojo validation rule in drools

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I am inserting let's say about 1000 pojos of type A in to the kiesession how can I add a rule in drools to do some task if duplicate pojos exists for A in the kiesession.

```
class A {
     private int someInt;
     private String someString;
}

function boolean checkDuplicate(List input) {
    int a = input.size();
    int b = ((List) input.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())).size();
    return a!=b;
}

dialect "java"
rule "ADuplicateRule"
   when
        $input : List( ) from collect(A())
        eval(checkDuplicate($input))
   then
        throw new Exception("A list has duplicate values");
end
```

The above approach is working but is there a better more simpler way to achieve this?

like to do validation on sum of a field of pojo in the kiesession we can just simply write this

```
$sumSomeInt: Integer(this > 90) from accumulate(A( $SomeInt: someInt ), sum($SomeInt))
```

is it possible to do something on the similar lines to check for duplicates?

Comment: Traditionally, value equality of POJOs could be approximated through projecting of a [hashcode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()), so collecting all previously seen hashCodes in a [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) might work for you. Caveats - there's a small chance of collisions, so you could get a false positive. Also, you'll likely need to apply a time or count window to prevent the hashset bloating indefinitely.

Comment: Is it acceptable in your case to delete duplicates on the early stage not to deal with 'bad data'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close:

```
rule "Duplicates Found"
when
  A( $i: someInt, $s: someString )
  List( size > 1 ) from collect( A( someInt == $i, someString == $s ) )
then 
  // handle the duplicate case
end
```

Adjust your equality check as needed. I would recommend not throwing an exception out of the 'then'.

Alternatively, you don't even need to collect a full list of duplicates; it's sufficient that there exists at least one duplicate. This makes your rule more like this:

```
rule "Duplicates found - v2"
when
  $a: A( $i: someInt, $s: someString )
  exists( A( this != $a, someInt == $i, someString == $s ))
then
  // handle the duplicates case
end
```

---

In these rules we're taking advantage of the fact that Drools will implicitly check all instances of `A` in working memory. So in the first rule, for each `A`, it will check to see if there are duplicates of that instance; if there are, the rule triggers. Otherwise it checks the next instance of `A`, and so on, until all instances of `A` have been evaluated.

The second rule relies on the same sort of workflow, but also includes a `this != $a` check on the `exists` clause to verify that the "duplicate" we found isn't actually the instance we're checking. Since the first rule only triggers for `List( size > 1 )`, it expects that the instance we're checking will be included in the result of the `collect`.