# Accumulate/Collect vs single java loop

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I have a use case in which let's say I have 100,000 pojos in the kiesession of type A and I want to apply some rules on it out of which two are -

1. Check is a duplicate value of type A exist.
2. sum of A.someInt is equal to the givenValue.

```
class A {
     private int someInt;
     private String someString;
}
```

For these two rules should I go with creating separate rules for them in drools like this

1. `$sumSomeInt: Integer(this > 90) from accumulate(A( $SomeInt: someInt ), sum($SomeInt))`
2. 

```
function boolean checkDuplicate(List input) {
    int a = input.size();
    int b = ((List) input.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())).size();
    return a!=b;
}

dialect "java"
rule "ADuplicateRule"
   when
        $input : List( ) from collect(A())
        eval(checkDuplicate($input))
   then
        throw new Exception("A list has duplicate values");
end
```

Or is it better to apply this in java using a single loop for this and doing both the things what I want to know is will applying these two approaches on 100k records give us a major performance difference

just a reminder I also have other rules so I have to use drools I don't want to apply some validation in java and some in drools  unless there is a major performance boost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drools optimizes the "when" clause. The "then", which is pure Java, is not optimized and is executed "as-is". `eval` statements are not optimized either and are bad practice and should be avoided at all costs. Just about anything you can do in an 'eval', you can do in a Drools native fashion.

Given the choice, in the "when", of doing something in Java via an `eval`, and doing something using Drools built-in structures and methods, always prefer doing it the Drools native way. 100k records isn't very many so it probably won't be noticeable at such a scale.

And you shouldn't be throwing exceptions -- that's also not a good practice. `retract` your inputs or something to force execution to terminate early.

I shared a better way of doing duplicate detection in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69395859/419705).

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer can you please provide more details about why shouldn't I throw an exception in  'then' in drl?

Comment: One more Question so you said that 100k records isn't very many, as I mentioned about I have like around 15 other basic rules[which null check and format validation of fields] which apply on individual pojos and only these two rule where I need to apply on all of the pojo of type A in your experience how much time do you time drools will be able to apply all these rules on 100k records I know it will depends upon many things like compute system where I am perform[just FYI it'll be lambda in my case] this but can you give some estimate like will it be in seconds or maybe minutes

Comment: Re the exception, you're forcing the drools engine to terminate abnormally. You're not going to get a legible stack trace out of it anyway, so why not just terminate processing more gracefully?

Comment: The impact of 10 vs 100 (or 1000 or 10k or...) objects in memory comes down to what those objects are, their size, and how cleanly they serialize. It's very hard to measure "time" because it will depend on how complex your objects are and how complex the operations your rules are doing. We can describe this in general terms (eg. `O(n)`) but it will also come down to the drools lifecycle -- namely the "matching" phase and how many times you reenter this phase based on changes to your working memory.